# Prevent button double click ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using an button in ionic2 app, and using the (click). But if I press 2 times on the button, the same function (lets say open a modal) shows twice. How can we prevent the double click or incidental multiple clicks over a button, while it loads the async function. 
I was hoping to have some dblclick event, and just prevent it, but I don't think ionic2 has that. I have tried using (tap) but it also accepts several and multiple clicks.

Do I need to deal with this manual/custom, and to set a boolean to true and false while using the async call, and use it as [disabled] property ?

Comment: You gave a pretty good answer to your own question. Did you try it?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [loading](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#loading) component just to achieve that.

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class Util {
  public progressBarLoader : any;
  constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
  }

  showLoader(timeInMilliseconds) {
    let progressBarLoader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait...",
      duration: timeInMilliseconds
    });
    progressBarLoader.present();
  }

  hideLoader(){
    try{
      if(this.progressBarLoader != null || this.progressBarLoader != undefined){
        this.progressBarLoader.dismiss();
      }
    }catch(e){      
      console.log("Busy Indecator not showing :: " + e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

when the button is tapped call `showLoader()` with very long time value, and when your async operation finished then you can call `hideLoader()`. This will avoid multiple tapping on the button and you dont have to deal with manually enabling/disabling the button.